# AWS Kinesis Streams, Create Stream Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, bigdata, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm a complete beginner of AWS Kinesis Streams, SO i am following

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/fundamental-stream.html

tutorial. As shown in the tutorial i install and configure the AWS CLI, then i try to Create a Stream by typing bellow command in CMD (I'm using windows)

> > aws kinesis create-stream --stream-name Foo --shard-count 1

This give bellow error,

> > Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://kinesis.N.Virginia.amazonaws.com/"

How can i over come this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint should be

```
kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

You must be setting the region/endpoint incorrectly.

Comment: Yes you are write. Thank you.